# How to make image clipping work for inverted images in fabric js?

Tags: image, html5-canvas, fabricjs

This works fine for normal images but when the **flipX property is set to true** then the clipping area gets distorted. This also happens when **angle property is set** to the image.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some code?

Comment: Thanks for responding .. i did it. Due to the objectCaching property the image wasnt rendered